# Object Data Source select method directly accesses the Data Access Layer?

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview, objectdatasource

In my Data Access Layer (i'm using a dataset), I have a couple of queries that retrieves different columns from a database table. Meanwhile, I have a business logic layer which have one method that based on input parameters, selects one of the queries from the DAL.

Now, I wish to use an object data source as the data source for a gridview on my webpage due to how easy it is to implement paging and sorting. However, it seems that the select method for the object data source goes directly to the data access layer as opposed to the business logic layer.

Is it possible to point the select method of the object data source to the method in the BLL? Or am I stuck with making multiple object data sources for the different queries I have in the DAL?

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand why you say

> it seems that the select method for the object data source goes
>   directly to the data access layer as opposed to the business logic
>   layer

It's up to you to specify which method get called, by specifying the TypeName and SelectMethod:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ODSData" runat="server" 
    SelectMethod="GetXXX" TypeName="BusinessLayer.MyClass"
```

However, if you want to see the Business Method from the Visual Studio Designer, you have to decorate the Business Layer method with:

```
 [System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute
            (System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Select, true)]
```